# AngularJS and material icons

Tags: angularjs, google-material-icons

Material Icons are working fine in my AngularJS app.

In my template.html :

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE86A;</i>
```

This works fine, the icon is displayed correctly.

But this code does not :

```
<div ng-repeat="x in pages">
    current icon : {{x.icon}}
    <br>
    <i class="material-icons">{{x.icon}}</i>
</div>
```

where pages is defined in the controller :

```
$scope.pages = [
{icon: "&#xE0B6;"},
{icon: "&#xE8F9;"},
{icon: "&#xE5CA;"}
];
```

I can see the right value of {{x.icon}}.

Why does

```
<i class="material-icons">{{x.icon}}</i>
```

not work ?

Comment: Try parsing  the value. it is getting printed as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ng-bind-html` and unsafe filter:

**templat.html**

```
 <i class="material-icons" ng-bind-html="x.icon | unsafe "></i>
```

**JS**

```
app.filter('unsafe',function($sce){
  return $sce.trustAsHtml
})
```